# Unreadable JSON answer in Swift

Tags: json, swift, encode

I'm using this code to send a post request to an api:

```
@IBAction func loadServicesTestButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            let headers = [
                "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "cache-control": "no-cache",
                "postman-token": "dded3e97-77a5-5632-93b7-dec77d26ba99"
            ]
            let postData = NSMutableData(data: "data={\"user_id\":\"1\",\"type_id\":\"2\"}".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://www.api.com")! as URL,
                                              cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                              timeoutInterval: 10.0)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
            request.httpBody = postData as Data

            let session = URLSession.shared
            let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
                if (error != nil) {
                    print(error!)
                } else {
                    if let dataNew = data, let responseString = String(data: dataNew, encoding: .utf8) {
                        print(responseString)                        

                    }

                }

            })

            dataTask.resume()
        }

    }
```

In answer I'm getting unreadable JSON like this:

```
{"status":"ok","answer":{"address":"\u041a\u0430\u043c\u044b\u0448\u0438, \u0434\u043e\u043c 98","created_at":"2019-02-12 12:48:24","updated_at":"2019-02-21 08:58:30","name":"\u0412\u043b\u0430\u0434\u0438\u043c\u0438\u0440 \u041a\u0443\u0437\u044c\u043c\u0438\u043d","user_type":1}}
```

how to encode this answer to get readable content? I tried JSONSerialization but didn't work. Any idea? Example code in my func will be greatly appreciated. Thank you all for your time and efforts.

Comment: Is the address made of non utf8 characters? appears that way

Comment: This is valid JSON. Address is `"Камыши, дом 98"` and name is `"Владимир Кузьмин"`. `JSONSerialization` (or better `Decodable`) is supposed to work. Assign the values to a label then you will see the Cyrillic letters.

Comment: Also you need not to call api in main thread. Use main thread when you are going to do UI work e.g. DispatchQueue.main.async {
            label.text = "name"
            table.reloadData()
        }

Comment: @vadian Thank you for your answer, attaching to label didn't work because I'm getting error here: Use of unresolved identifier 'responseString'
        let userAdd = responseString[indexPath.row]
        cell.userAddress.text = userAdd["address"] as? String

Comment: @RajSharma Thanks, I removed DispatchQueue.main.async

Comment: That's a different error. `responseString` is only visible in the scope (`{}`) where it's declared. You need to assign the result of the JSON parsing to the data source array. But the JSON in the question is only one item. There is no array.

Comment: @JessicaKimble You can get the string from dictionary and set to label. It will show the proper name i.e. Владимир Кузьмин

Please check the reference
https://github.com/rheyansh/TemporaryData/blob/master/sample.png

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
do {

    let form = DateFormatter()

    form.dateFormat = "yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

    let dec = JSONDecoder()

    dec.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

    dec.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(form)

    let res = try dec.decode(Root.self,from:dataNew)

    print(res)
}
catch {

    print(error)
}
```

---

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let status: String
    let answer: Answer
}

struct Answer: Codable {
    let address, name: String
    let createdAt, updatedAt: Date
    let userType: Int
}
```

This

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
```

should be inside the callback for any UI update as by default  `session.dataTask(with:` runs in background thread